# How to get the label of an A HREF with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to scrape data. I've been able to select the entire anchor tag that contains the data I need using the following XPATH

```
doc.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_NavigationWithContentOverRelated_ContentOverRelated_PageHeaderUserControl_CoachName"]/a')
```

What I really need is just the label of the Anchor tag of the following Anchor (John Doe)

```
<a href="/local/team/records/coaches.aspx?gendersport=boys,football&amp;schoolid=cb90bc08-daf2-403f-a8aa-7fbffffed296">John Doe</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `/text()` to the xpath did it